# Can a Grails Domain Class inherit from a class that is not a domain class?

Tags: class, inheritance, grails, dns

I tried to do this, but it insists on their being a table of the base class.  I tried using         tablePerHierarchy false as well and that didn't make any difference.

I have a few domain classes that share a bunch of methods that operate on an inherited transient field.  I had hoped that just having the class over in the non-domain section "/src/..." would be enough for GORM to realize there isn't a base class in the database.

When I put the class in the src section I get a different error.  It no longer maps the specific class.
Error 500: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: Summarypage is not mapped [from Summarypage where id = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Summarypage is not mapped [from Summarypage where id = ?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.  If the base class is an abstract class it does the right thing.

Thanks anyway everyone.